# Build a Azure Resource Group-project (.deployproj) with TeamCity

Tags: azure, powershell, teamcity, azure-resource-manager, dsc

I've got an Azure Resource Group-project (.deployproj) in Visual Studio which deploys fine. It is containing a DSC.ps1 file and a CustomScripts.ps1 file which is referenced by the template.json.

I want to deploy this project from TeamCity, but **I can't find the way to build** the project. During deploy Visual Studio outputs:

```
11:01:21 - Build started.
11:01:21 - Project "AzureResources.deployproj" (StageArtifacts target(s)):
11:01:21 - Project "AzureResources.deployproj" (ContentFilesProjectOutputGroup target(s)):
11:01:21 - Done building project "ESS.AzureResources.deployproj".
11:01:21 - Done building project "ESS.AzureResources.deployproj".
```

It seems it puts the DSC.ps1 file inside a zip-archive together with some dependencies before it runs the `Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1` which in turns does the deploy. The output of the build is put in `bin/Debug/staging`.

How can I perform the build from TeamCity/command line? Through msbuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the .deployproj has a deploy action, only build.  To deploy you'd need an additional step in TeamCity to invoke the Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 and point it to the build output.

Comment: That is right, but how do I perform the build is my question? I need to build it, in order for the DSC-script with dependencies to be put in a zip-archive. I can't figure out how to do the build from command-line.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeamCity - but if you goal is deploy you can look at a few options. 1) run the Deploy-AzureRmResourceGroup.ps1 file in your deployproj from TeamCity and point it to source.  That script will package your DSC script for you. 2) if you have other things that are "built" just find out how you do msbuild from teamcity.  The "build" stage of the deployproj does nothing but file copy (to build output), so if you don't mind deploying from source, that's the simplest option.  The key here for DSC is that done using the PS1 script, it's *not* done by msbuild.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that the ps1-script also archives the DSC for me. Great, thanks!